# Unable to insert POST variables into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm a beginner in CodeIgniter and I'm trying to insert the value that I'm getting from the post into my database, for which I'm using the following code:

View Class:

```
<form method="POST">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" name="login">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

Controller Class:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model("membership_model");
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $content='';
        return $this->load->view('auth/login');
        if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
            $content['data'] = $this->membership_model->create_user($username,$password);
        }
}
```

Model Class:

```
class Membership_model extends CI_Model {
         public function create_user($username,$password){
            $this->db->set('display_name',$username);
             $this->db->set('password',$password);
             $this->db->insert("table1");
             return true;
         }
     }
```

But when I hit submit, I do not get any data in my database for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think when you press the submit button, the page just reloads. To submit data to the controller you have to specify the ``action`` in your ``<form>``

Comment: So `<form method="POST" action="">`?

Comment: Correct! ``action`` should contain the route which points to the controller.

Comment: #h2o attach the console log on your browser whenever you get an error, whenever posting a question.

Comment: @h2o check my updates. There were 2 problems with your controller and model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work well.

Controller modification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

    class Auth extends Controller{
        public function index(){
            if($this->input->method() == "post") {
                $this->load->model("membership_model");
                $username=$this->input->post('username');
                $password=$this->input->post('password');
                $content='';
                
                if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
                    $content['data'] = $this->membership_model->create_user($username,$password);
                }
            }
            return $this->load->view('auth/login');
    }
```

Model modification:

```
public function create_user($username, $password){
    $data = array(
        'display_name'=>$username,
        'display_name'=>$password
    );
    $this->db->insert("table1", $data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: This gives an error on $request saying `Undefined variable '$request'`

Comment: @h2o just updated. Small error from $this->$request->getMethod()

Comment: Doing this gives me 1 warning `Undefined property: Auth::$$request` and 1 error  `Call to a member function getMethod() on null`

Comment: @heo your ci version?

Comment: I'm currently using CI 4.0 and php 8.0

Comment: @h2o then your controller should extend from BaseController. Why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238792/discussion-between-daniel-kaminski-and-h2o).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons for data not entering your database, but yet not showing any errors. some of which include:

- No action attribute in your form, thus the page just reloads. You should put the route to the controller that handles the data e.g '/auth` as your action atttribute
- The database has some sort of constraint, that prevents data from entering it. For example, you might have accidentally put a `NOT NULL` constraint on one of your fields in the databse. Thus the record will not enter because that field is empty

Comment: Okay, so I have added action="auth" in my form and the database structure is something like this: https://imgur.com/a/7SylMts and its still not working so I dont think any of these are the problems

Comment: Send your route file

Comment: It just says: `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Comment: @H2O I've added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any action end point when you submitting the form. So it's basically refreshing the page. So you should do

1. specify the action in your  with route url.
2. And still if not solve check the database field and check the value you passing whether it's null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. You are calling `return $this->load->view('auth/login');` before the process that inserts data into your db. Try changing your

Controller Class  from:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model("membership_model");
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $content='';
        return $this->load->view('auth/login');
        if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
            $content['data'] = $this->membership_model->create_user($username,$password);
        }
}
```

to:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model("membership_model");
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $content='';
        if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
            $content['data'] = $this->membership_model->create_user($username,$password);
        }
        return $this->load->view('auth/login');

}
```

Comment: Doing this gives me 1 warning `Undefined property: Auth::$db` and 1 error `Call to a member function insert() on null`

Comment: Pls send the full error

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GvZCS4S Full error

Comment: @H2O thats a wrong link

Comment: Resent the link

Comment: Add `$this->load->database();` to Your auth.php,